# How to get data from modal in same component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have the component, order-book.component.ts in which I set up this column on the ag-grid. The idea is that in the SplitButtonComponent, I have set up a button called 'Split' and that when it is clicked a modal should open up. I am trying to access the data so I can use some properties from the data to display in the modal but the console log in ngOnInit keeps showing an empty array. I also tried looking at the dialogRef instance and within the _containerInstance property, I can see the rowData object and the data. However, I can't access that same data in ngOnInit. Can anyone help?

Here is the code for the 'Sales Credit' column.

```
if(array[obj]['children][subobj].field == 'salesCreditAmount'){
 array[obj]['children][subobj]['valueFornatter'] = this.numberControl === 'mm' ? 
 this.numberParser : this.millionParser;
 array[obj]['children][subobj]['aggFunc'] = 'mySum';
 array[obj]['children][subobj]['cellRenderer'] = SplitButtonComponent;
 array[obj]['children][subobj]['cellEditorParans'] = { precision: 2 }
}
```

Here is the code for the SplitButtonComponen, specifically the ts and html.

```
export class SplitButtonComponent implements OnInit, ICellRendererAngularComp {     
public params: any;
hover: boolean = false;
dialogRef!: any;
@ViewChild('splitDialog') splitDialog!: TemplateRef <any>;    
rowDataCell: any;
constructor (public dialog: MatDialog, @Inject (MAT _DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) 
{ }

ngOnInit(): void {
console. log('Data passed to dialog:', this.data);     
}

agInit (params: ICellRendererParams): void {
this.params = params;
console.log (this.params);
}

refresh (params: ICellRendererParams) {
return false;     
}

onSplitclick (): void {
console.log('is params reaching:', this .params);
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.splitDialog,{     
width: '500px',      
maxHeight:'90vh' ,     
data: { rowData: this.params},
panelClass: ['split-dialog'],     
});
dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(() => {console.log('Dialog instance:',dialogRef);     

    }); }
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="cell-content" (mouseover)= "hover = true" (mouseleave) ="hover = false">
    <span> {{ params.value  }}</span>       
    <button *ngIf="hover" class="btn button-primary" color=blue 
    (click)="onSplitClick()">Split</button>
</div>

<div>       
<ng-template #splitDialog>
   <h2 mat-dialog-title>Split</h2>          
   <mat-dialog-content>              
      <p>Split content...</p>       
   </mat-dialog-content>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>
       <button (click)="saveChanges()" class ="btn button-secondary">Save 
        Changes</button>        
       <button (click)="closeDialog()" class ="btn button-primary">Cancel</button>
    </div>

    </ng-template> 
</div>
```